# Get rid of annotations

Tags: annotations, rascal

We know how to [declare new annotations](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/Annotation/Annotation.html) and how to [assign them](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Replacement/Replacement.html) to nodes.

What’s the good way to do the following?

- delete a particular annotation from a node
- throw away all annotations of a node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some library functions in the `Node` module of the standard library. See also [Node](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Node/Node.html) in the tutor documentation:

- [delAnnotation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Node/delAnnotation/delAnnotation.html)
- [delAnnotations](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Node/delAnnotation/delAnnotations.html)
- [delAnnotationsRec](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Node/delAnnotation/delAnnotationsRec.html)